# undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs undefined (windows)

Tags: rabbitmq

I tried to change the base directory (Initially it was %APPDATA%\Roaming\RabbitMQ) by setting up the environment variables like RABBITMQ_BASE, RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE and RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE to following location: C:\RabbitMQ\ProgramData.
then I re-installed the service
[image]

Now once I restart service, I'm getting this error while opening the http api.
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone please help here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi - did you get anywhere with this issue?